# Subsets of relatively prime numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I was working on the problem "The numbers 1,2,3,...,1019 are split into non-overlapping subsets so that in each subset there are no numbers a,b (a≠b) such that a is divisible by b. Find the minimal number of such subsets." However, I was unable to find any plausible way to calculate such a solution. Does anyone know how I am supposed solve this?

Comment: I'd have thought a good first step would be to try to write down examples of such collections.  You could just take each element, but presumably that's not minimal.  What about $\{1\}$, then all the primes, then all the products of two primes, then all the products of three primes, and so on?  That's only $10$ or so sets.  Can you find anything smaller?  Once you have a good candidate you can try to prove it is minimal

Comment: As a hint to finding a lower bound:  find a bunch of natural numbers $≤1019$ such that no two can be in the same subset.

Comment: Finishing the argument that @lulu provided, notice that $1$ necessitates its own bucket, $2$ needs a bucket that doesn't have $1$ in it, $4$ needs a bucket that doesn't have $2$ or $1$ in it, and so on. This shows that we need at least 10 buckets, so 10 is optimal.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

Consider the natural numbers $\{1,2,2,2^2,\cdots, 2^9\}$.  No two of these can be in the same subset, hence you need at least $10$ subsets.

On the other hand, it is possible to do it with $10$ subsets.  Namely:  For $i\in \{0,\cdots, 9\}$ Let $S_i$ be the subset consisting of those natural numbers which have prime factorizations containing exactly $i$ primes, counted with multiplicities.  Thus $S_0=(1)$, $S_1$ is the set of primes, $S_2$ is the set of products of two primes (possibly not distinct) and so on.  It is clear that every natural number $≤2^{10}=1024$ is in exactly one of the $S_i$ so we are done.